# Annotated Spring @Controller also as Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

Can an annotated Spring MVC Controller also be annotated with @Component/@Service type of annotations and be used both as a controller and as a bean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit: placing more emphasis on the software design aspect, and updating the API link to SpringV3*

As mentioned in other answers, this is not an ideal approach to Spring MVC, but nevertheless the controller will already be available for autowiring in your ApplicationContext.

It's already a Bean in your ApplicationContext, so you can auto-wire it by type. There's no need to add an @Component annotation.

From the Spring API Docs: "This annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning."

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html

The same holds true for @Service.

Although I've done it myself, I would not normally recommend this design approach.

If possible, refactor the required functionality into a separate bean, which can then be (auto-)wired into both the @Controller, and any other bean, as required.

If, as you have commented, you are 'cornered' into this decision (as I was, by previous design choices), then so be it.

HTH

Comment: Not everything that's possible is also advisable. Using a web controller as dependency is an awful design flaw

Comment: True, but I answered his question, recommended against it, and suggested an alternate approach. I think it's important to provide the answer, even if it's inadvisable on a design level.

Comment: (the question was 'can' it, rather than 'should' it)

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Edit your answer and I'll remove the downvote (I can't unless you edit it). Hint: how about changing the 2.5.6 javadoc link to a current one

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I am aware that it is not the best solution, but as I commented in Patricks answer, I just want to expose what is already exposed via other mechanism (DWR) and it would require to hand write a delegate with no logic whatsoever.  On the other hand, I know that a controller somhow ends up inside the Spring container, though the @Controller annotation has no way to specify a name...so I guess it would have to be autowired by type which is ok, just haven't tried.

Comment: @Sean, ok, I've updated the link and increased emphasis on the design aspect. @pakman, I understand your perspective. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

It *can* but it *shouldn't*. A web controller should be an entry point, nothing else.

Any reusable logic it performs should be in a dedicated [service layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Layers_Pattern), not in the controller itself

Comment: Thanks.  Normally I would do that, but I just want to expose the same service as a DWR service and as a Rest service.  I could write a controller that would then talk to the service, but it will have no logic.  It will simply be a delagate to the service; not a big fan of hand writing delegates or proxies.

Comment: @pakman OK, how about putting the controller methods into an abstract class and creating two instances

Answer (score 1):

No, sounds like it's doing too much.  One or the other, not both.  I don't know if it's possible (I doubt it), but I'm sure it's not advisable.

Comment: it is possible, but +1 for recommending against it

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should hear more about patterns like Front Controller, MVC, DAO and Multitier architecture and so on.